# docker run -v : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to run

```sh
docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
      -v $(pwd)/scripts:/root/scripts \
      --link "${DYNAMO_CONTAINER}:localhost" \
      amazon/aws-cli dynamodb batch-write-item \
          --request-items file:///root/scripts/sampledata.json \
          --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

The error I am getting is

```sh
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Unable to load paramfile file:///root/scripts/sampledata.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/scripts/sampledata.json'
```

I have also tried

```sh
docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
      -v $(pwd)/scripts:/root \
      --link "${DYNAMO_CONTAINER}:localhost" \
      amazon/aws-cli dynamodb batch-write-item \
          --request-items file:///root/scripts/sampledata.json \
          --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

and

```sh
docker run --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws \
      -v $(pwd)/scripts:/root \
      --link "${DYNAMO_CONTAINER}:localhost" \
      amazon/aws-cli dynamodb batch-write-item \
          --request-items file:///root/sampledata.json \
          --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

On the last one I'm still getting a `No such file...` error although with a different path.

The structure of the host `scripts` directory is

```
scripts
├── sampledata.json
└── other.sh
```

What am I doing wrong... ?

Comment: what system are you running on ? maybe its a  permission related issue ?

Comment: Two sanity checks: if you put `echo` at the front of the line, what does the `-v` option expand to? If you `docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/scripts:/root busybox ls /root/scripts` do you see the bind-mounted content?